# Full text search in Spring boot with PostgreSQL Database using Hibernate Search is not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, full-text-search, jpql

I'm trying to build a full text search application with Spring Boot using PostgreSQL Database.

Reference: https://dev.to/fabiothiroki/setup-spring-and-postgres-for-full-text-search-4n97

It's a good article to start. But, this application works for 1 entity only at a time.

Problem I'm facing is:

1. Cannot register multiple functions. Due to this not able to work with other entities. Latest function only will be registered. Ex: `pfts` won't work as it is not the latest registered function, `cfts` will work.
2. Tried to pass search parameters/fields dynamically. But not working. Looks like columns/fields need to passed during function registration only. Ex: Below `pfts` works,`cfts` doesn't work. Enabled Hibernate parameter bindings and saw the columns/fields are passed correctly. Still, doesn't work.

Sample Code below with above 2 scenarios:

```
public class FullTextSearchContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("pfts", new SQLFunctionTemplate(BooleanType.INSTANCE, "to_tsvector(name || description) @@ to_tsquery(?1)"));
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("cfts", new SQLFunctionTemplate(BooleanType.INSTANCE, "to_tsvector(?1) @@ to_tsquery(?2)"));
    }

}
```

Basically I need to do full text search on multiple tables/entities with multiple columns (i.e., columns/fields to be passed dynamically to `to_tsvector()` as the columns/fields will be varying according to the tables/entities)

Note: No Table Joining concept.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Vlad Mihalcea could you please look into this issue?